# How do I remove 1 char in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to remove a character of string in makefile, for example

```
FOO = 123-456-789-
all:
  # want to display 123-456-789
  echo "$(FOO)"
```

I want to remove the last char in sting "-", which mean
how to let "123-456-789-" become "123-456-789"

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you know the character you want to replace, the following snippet must work:

```
FOO = 123-456-789-

all:
        echo $(FOO:-=)
```

Comment: GOOD i was getting crazy, do you know why mine is not working?

Comment: I think you are confusing it with the bash syntax `${VAR%%SUFFIX}`. Make will not understand that. Something like ` bash -c 'TEST=$(FOO); echo $${TEST%%-}'` would work (note I am escaping the `$`) but I find it too verbose.